Migrating from Mint to Ubuntu 24.04 Cinnamon
Here is what I am setting out to accomplish.
I want to migrate from using Mint 21 on a machine to Ubuntu 24.04 Cinnamon.
The reason I am doing this is to standardize OS across my home network.
The end users on this machine have data and app specific configurations that they would rather not have to resetup.
Since Mint is a fork of Ubuntu I do not see any compatibility issues.
So I am wondering if I can simply:

Run the dd command and send the entirety of the / dir to an external storage.
Run the dd command after installing Ubuntu 24.04 and successfully import the data from external storage to the new install.

Is this actually something that is possible, or is there a nuance here that I need to consider?
Would it be a better practice to just copy the /etc and /home dirs and import that into the new install?
I am wanting to do this with as little impact to the users on this machine as possible while avoiding data corruption and loss.
I am already keenly aware that performing a back up needs to be done as a contingency.

WIthout being more specific about the applications and data the question is difficult to answer. If you dd the whole disk you might end up with a copy of your Mint system.
I would expect all user specific data to be in /home, but you have to make sure that all users are created with the same name and user ID, and there might be incompatibilities if the application versions don't match.

This question is similar to: How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You didn't specify your partitioning scheme; as with 24.04 & 24.10 where the ubuntu-desktop-installer is used; a forced format occurs with / so your manually installed apps won't survive. You'll also need to have a separate /home partition, unless you install a flavor that uses calamares (Budgie doesn't!). Linux Mint isn't a fork (only some parts only are); it isn't a full distribution only providing some packages, and using Ubuntu binaries & adjusting via runtime adjustments for some too; its a based on system.
